# how to display all columns of table

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, average

i am working on a store producer for a filter. i have many types of checks in my sp just like

```
if(@cityId!=0 and @sourceLatitude!=0 and @sourceLongitude!=0 
    and @KM!=0 and  @food='' and @price='' and @sort='')
```

but i show just one table against all checks but i am also using group and AVG().

my question is, is there any way to display all fields without writing in group by.

my code

```
SELECT
    
--cast(AVG(rr.Rates ) as decimal(10,5)) Rating,
round(AVG(rr.Rates ),2) Rating,
[dbo].[Fun_distanceCalculate](r.Latitude,r.Longitude,@sourceLatitude,@sourceLongitude) AS Distance,
[dbo].[Fun_calculate_delivery_fee](r.Latitude,r.Longitude,@sourceLatitude,@sourceLongitude) AS DeliveryCharges,
 r.Id,
r.IsActive,
r.CreatedDate,
Name,
TagLine,
ApproximateCostPerPerson,
FullAddress2,
FullAddress,
Tags,
IsRecommend,
Longitude,
DeliveryTime,
IsOnline,
Logo,
ImageUrl,
Latitude,
ProductDiscount,
TagLine,
IsApproved,
Salt,
Email,
PhoneNumber,
CityId,
CountryId


     

    FROM [dbo].[Restaurants] r left join [dbo].[RestaurantReviews] rr
    
    on r.Id=rr.RestaurantId
     WHERE r.IsActive = 1 and r.IsApproved=1 and ((r.CityId=@cityId) OR @KM > [dbo].[Fun_distanceCalculate](r.Latitude,r.Longitude,@sourceLatitude,@sourceLongitude))
    --ORDER BY Id  DESC
    --OFFSET  @PageNumber  ROWS 
    --FETCH NEXT @pageSize ROWS ONLY
    group by r.Id,Name,
r.IsActive,
TagLine,
ApproximateCostPerPerson,
FullAddress2,
FullAddress,
IsOnline,
Tags,
Logo,
IsRecommend,
Longitude,
DeliveryTime,
ImageUrl,
Latitude,
ProductDiscount,
TagLine,
IsApproved,
Salt,
Email,

PhoneNumber,
CityId,
    r.CreatedDate,
CountryId
```

Comment: Your code is for ms sql server, not for mysql.

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: Displaying an aggregate result (e.g. avg or sum) is in very stark contradiction of displaying every field from every record (you included the id field there, which I assume is the PK for your table). If you group by on the primary key, then every row will be a separate group, so the average will be equal to the field's value. You really need to think your business requirements through because these do not make any sense at the moment!

Comment: Nope. If you have a column in your SELECT clause that is not being aggregated by a function like `avg`, `sum`, `max`, etc then it must be present in your GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the aggregation to a CTE, then join the CTE to the main query.

```
WITH AvgRates
AS
(
r.Id
round(AVG(rr.Rates ),2) AS Rating,
FROM [dbo].[Restaurants] r left join [dbo].[RestaurantReviews] rr on r.Id=rr.RestaurantId
--can use the WHERE filtering here or in the final select
GROUP BY r.Id
)
SELECT
av.Rating,
--rest of your query
FROM [dbo].[Restaurants] r left join [dbo].[RestaurantReviews] rr on r.Id=rr.RestaurantId
 INNER JOIN AvgRates av ON r.Id = av.Id
--rest of your WHERE filtering etc.
```